# ship class Object detection with custom model weights

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, image-classification, object-detection

I have made a model to classify different categories of ships(yacht,catamaran,rubber boat) in Python and i hit a 70%  accuracy in training so now i **have my weights.hdf5 file**.Now i need to **object detection** the images i used with boundaries boxes and rectangles to find the **different ships in each image**, like a Yolo pretrained model but **with my own weights** that i trained for classes,so that the detector is going to find the ship in the image and **display is's label** with is's **probability**,
etc **yacht(70.0% )rubber boat(65.0%)**...
Can anyone with some more experience drive me to achieving this task?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `keras.models.load_model` to load the `hdf5` model file. See also [the tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize).

```
# saving the model
model = ...  # Get model (Sequential, Functional Model, or Model subclass)
model.save('weights.hdf5')

# loading the model
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('weights.hdf5')
```

Comment: tensorflow has the option for object detection but with weights from other known pretrained datasets.My problem is that i have the weights from my model and i want to object detect with my model.I suppose your referink to (https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_object_detection.ipynb)

Comment: The code above works the same when using a custom model. You first have to save the model and it's weights to a file using the `.save()` method, which you can then load in other scripts using the `load_model` function.